# How can I increase the width of a column in a table?

Tags: php, html

The input of "file name" is a long variable, I tried changing the width for the `<th>` and the `<td>` but nothing seemed to work. Then I decided to put the `whitespace: nowrap;` however when I did that it clashed with my other columns and the writing for filename just went over them. How can I fix this?

```
<table class="responstable" rules='all' style='border-collapse: collapse;'>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Client id</th>
        <th>File Name</th>  
        <th>Payer ID</th>       
        <th>Patient_f_name</th>
        <th>Patient_l_name</th>
        <th>cpt_code</th>
        <th>insurance_voucher</th>
        <th>paitent_id</th>
        <th>acc_number</th>
        <th>service_dos</th>
        <th>local_charge_number</th>
        <th>charge_amount</th>
        <th>insurance_name_insurance_company</th>
        <th>paid_amount_payment</th>
        <th>paid_amount_vouchers</th>   
    </tr>
</thead>
  <?php 
    while($row = pg_fetch_array($result))
    { 
  ?>

  <tbody>


    <tr <?=$row['flag'] ? "style='background-color: #fcf8e3'" : '';?>>

     <td><?php echo $row['voucher_id']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['client_id']; ?></td>
     <td style="white-space: nowrap"><?php echo $row['file_name']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['payer_id']; ?></td> 
     <td><?php echo $row['patient_f_name']; ?></td> 
     <td><?php echo $row['patient_l_name']; ?></td> 
     <td><?php echo $row['cpt_code'];?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['insurance'];?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['patient_id'] ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['acc_number'] ?></td>
```

Comment: Please set up a demo showing us the problem.  For example, we don't need to see your PHP code.  Show us a table with a few rows of actual data that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: How can i add a demonstration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{width:700px};
```

Put this in your css style.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify column width in pixels

```
<td width="300"><?php echo $row['file_name']; ?></td>
```

or in percentage of overall table width

```
<td width="20%"><?php echo $row['file_name']; ?></td>
```

Choose the numbers that suit you, instead of 300 pixels or 20%.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by setting min-width:200px property to your td.

- If you set that to specific td with class="filename", the only that
  column will be resized.

  If you set that to table>tr>td then all the columns of the table will
  be set to that width uniformly.

Answer (score -1):

Try `Colspan` and `Rowspan`. Hope it will help.

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">A</td>
        </tr>
     </table>
   </body>
 </html>
```